# Storing text/image file in mysql database

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to store .doc/.txt or image files to stroe in database directly making attributes of type blob?I neewd a good working example for storing files inside database and also obviously retrieving them from database as original.

Comment: Well yes... you can store pretty much anything as a blob, but you have to read/write it as a byte-stream. Example in which language ?!

Comment: if i get an example in php then it will be best for mine

Comment: Using BLOBs in a DBMS for binary files (like JPEG and various document formats) usually scales up poorly, because the DBMS becomes a bottleneck for storing and retrieving them. You're much better off with some kind of shared file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog entry http://mirificampress.com/permalink/saving_a_file_into_mysql describes the overall process in quite allot of detail for php.